# jQuery Moblie: passing parameters and dynamically load the content of a page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, parameters

I know it's a base problem, but I wasn't able to find anything fitting my situation.

I have a jQuery Mobile page with a list of elements. The elements references to a second pages which has a content that depends on what element where choose (for example a list of articles and choosing an article it should show the relative text). Basically I have to pass a parameter between pages.

I tried to do that using AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "index.html#page2",
    data : "id="+id,    
    dataType : 'json'
    type: "GET"
});
```

But i wasn't able to get the results in the second page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look of your URL: `index.html#page2`. You are trying to navigate to an internal page (one already in the DOM). If this is the case, then make the logic in JavaSCript on `#page2` and when you link to `#page2`, save the `id` value in a variable that the JavaScript on `#page2` can access.

Something like:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="myList">
    <li>
        <a href="#page2" data-id="987">This is some fake text... Click for More</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
$(document).delegate('#page1', 'pageinit', function () {

    //bind to click event for all links in the `#myList` UL
    $(this).find('#myList').find('a').bind('click', function () {

        //save the ID of this list-item to a global variable so it can be used later
        window.myId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    });
});
$(document).delegate('#page2', 'pageshow', function () {

    //get the ID saved as a global variable
    var currentId = window.myId;

    //now do logic for second page
});
</script>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/wFdet/

Comment: Ok i got the idea but it doesn't work. I changed pageinit to 'pageinit' and now is better, but I think the redirect part is missing. When I click on the link it does nothing.

Comment: the second page part is working. But the first page one it's not being execute.

Comment: I updated my answer, I forgot to add the `data-url` of the second page to the `href` attribute of the links.