# How to pass data from one page to another page html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a **page1.html** which contains set of data

`{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}`

and a link

`<a target='_blank' href='page2.html'>Click To Navigate</a>`

which will navigate to **page2.html**.

I would like to ask how can I pass all the data above in `page1.html` to `page2.html` so that I can use them in `page2.html`.

What I tried to use is `localStorage`, but I can store only 1 set of data at a time, so if in my `page1.html` have many set of data, same key but different value they will be overlapped when I store them in localStorage, then I can not pass all these set of data to the `page2.html`.

Anyone got an idea?
Thank you so much

Comment: Are you able to use PHP sessions at all?

Comment: @AndyHolmes He says he wants to do it in javascript

Comment: You could create an array of data objects to pass. `[{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2},{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}]`

Comment: The most common way is URL params( or hash params in SPA). <a href="page.html#key1=value1&key2=value2"> and then in page2, use location.hash to read these values

Comment: You could temporary store them in a cookie.. https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from one HTML page to another HTML page using JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508818/how-to-pass-data-from-one-html-page-to-another-html-page-using-jquery)

Comment: @Rob he didn't say he's using jQuery, this looks more like vanilla js.

Comment: @AlejandroIván There are several related answers using vanilla js on SO he should search for. This one was more direct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer data from one HTML file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502071/transfer-data-from-one-html-file-to-another)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it using Javascript, there's no restriction of which kind of object you can pass.
For instance, if you have several key-value objects:

```
var firstData = {
    'key1' : 'value1',
    'key2' : 'value2'
};
```

and

```
var secondData = {
    'key1' : 'value3',
    'key2' : 'value4'
};
```

you could enclose them using a Javascript array:

```
// This is on page1.html
var myData = [ firstData, secondData ];
```

and pass that array using localStorage.

**Javascript on page1.html**

```
// Set the variable
localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', myData );
```

**Javascript on page2.html**

```
// Get the variable
var myData = localStorage['objectToPass'];
localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' ); // Clear the localStorage
var firstData = myData[0];
var secondData = myData[1];
alert('firstData: ' + firstData + '\nsecondData: ' + secondData);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use javascript to do this, you can do the following (explains it really well)
- https://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/scriptpass.html

Also, you can use HTML5 to pass objects from a page to another page of your choise. In order to do this, you would create a session like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
```

And then to read the session you would do this:

```
sessionStorage.getItem('key');
```

This is a really good example on a webpage on how this can be achieved:http://demos.w3avenue.com/html5-unleashed-tips-tricks-and-techniques/sample-09-sessionstorage-demo.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use the localstorage with JSON method (**JSON.parse**) to parse a JSON string and construct the JavaScript value or object described by the string. The reverse operation is accomplished by the other method (**JSON.stringify**) to convert a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string.

javascript on the first page:

```
var data = {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'};
localStorage.setItem("object_name",JSON.stringify(data));
```

javascript on the second page.

```
var data = localStorage.getItem("object_name");
localStorage.clear(); //clean the localstorage
var value1 = JSON.parse(data).key1;
var value2 = JSON.parse(data).key2;
```

So now value1 and value2 in the second page contain the value of value1 and value2 of the first page.