# Passing a paginated listing info from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery

Within a *Bootstrap 4* card, I have a table listing books with 3 columns, of which the first contains a checkbox for each book. The *count* of the books selected by the user is displayed in the card's footer.

```js
var countChecked = function() {

  var $checkBox = $(this),
    $checkContainer = $checkBox.closest('table'),
    $checkedBoxes = $checkContainer.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),
    checkedCount = $checkedBoxes.length;

  $("#books_count").text(checkedCount);

};

$("#books").find("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', countChecked);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container p-0">
  <div id="books" class="card mx-1 my-1">
    <div class="card-header">Pick books</div>
    <div class="card-body p-0">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-sm m-0">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td><input class="add" type="checkbox" name="add_1" value="1"></td>
            <td>Don Quixote</td>
            <td>Miguel de Cervantes</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input class="add" type="checkbox" name="add_2" value="2"></td>
            <td>Ulysses</td>
            <td>James Joyce</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input class="add" type="checkbox" name="add_3" value="3"></td>
            <td>The Great Gatsby</td>
            <td>F. Scott Fitzgerald</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input class="add" type="checkbox" name="add_4" value="4"></td>
            <td>War and Peace</td>
            <td>Leo Tolstoy</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer border-top-0">
      You selected <strong id="books_count">0</strong> books
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that, in the real-life project, the books listing is *paginated* and I need to pass the books *count* from one page to another (and update it with the books selected on each page), to be able to get the correct count.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can't you just wrap this in a form and have server return the filtered data based on what is posted? Or be more specific about how pagination works

Comment: possibly doublicate of.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599781/how-to-pass-data-from-one-page-to-another-page-html

you can also use cookies.

Comment: @charlietfl I need (almost) instant count display. I was considering local storage but I am currently unfamiliar (and uncomfortable) with local storage related techniques.

Comment: LocalStorage is very very simple to use.

Comment: you might be able to count the checked book number, but you must need the exact books that have been checked right ?

Comment: @TowkirAhmed It seems to me that I would need an array of books to *pass* from one page to another, *update* and *count*.

Comment: It is possible to do with `localstorage`, why don't you handle it from server end ?