# Send data to another page - html

Tags: javascript, html

Hello I wanted to send data from one html page to another

For eg this is my index.html page

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var uname = "karan"; // I want to send this
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is newPage.html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log(uname); // I want the uname form index.html
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have already tried declaring a new class in another javascript file but it gives `undefined`

Is there any way I can do this? Thank you

Comment: I believe there is an answer there: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599781/how-to-pass-data-from-one-page-to-another-page-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36599781/how-to-pass-data-from-one-page-to-another-page-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use session storage like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("uname", "karan");
```

and retrieve it like this on another page:

```
console.log(sessionStorage.getItem("uname"));
```